# Appharbor deployment "Contains no tests"

Tags: c#, wcf, appharbor

I have a WCF project that I'm trying to deploy to [AppHarbor](https://appharbor.com/). The service works fine locally, ALL tests pass locally, basically, there are no issues locally. When I push to get it deployed, it builds fine, but follows with "Build contains no tests". I have even removed all the existing tests I've written and put a dummy on in there that is guaranteed to pass (basically just `Assert.IsTrue(0 == 0)`).

In the log ("Details"), I get:

```
Build succeeded.
```

However, I do also get:

```
5 Warning(s)
0 Error(s)
```

but that is just "e is not defined" (I haven't done anything inside the catch for a try/catch yet, that will come, I just want to get this up and running.

I've searched and searched on the AppHarbor site for some insight into this, but I've found nothing. Has anyone seen anything like this?

**
Using the built in test framework for Visual Studio (Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll).

Comment: Can you point to the solution so we can try it ourselves?  If not, can you give some more details about the test project? (which test framework, etc)

Comment: Is the unit test framework one of the ones we support? http://support.appharbor.com/kb/getting-started/running-unit-tests-after-build In particular, please check your NUnit version, if that's what you're using.

Comment: I've tried with both MSTest AND with Nunit 2.5.9, both of which are supported, and for both, I'm still getting "Build contains no tests"

Comment: Have you tried to start from scratch doing just a simple hello world deployment to reduce the number of possible issues you having?

Comment: We've just updated Gallio and NUnit, could I get you to give it another try? If it doesn't work then please create a support ticket at https://appharbor.com/support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version of AppHarbor now properly works with the problems I'm using. I don't know what changed (it definitely was not my code, I got sidetracked on a couple of different projects, but I'm back to the original project and it works on appharbor now).